# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'banane'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, spring

I've spent several days now trying to look for an answer to my issue on stackoverflow but without success. I also re-installed mysql but to no avail. Everytime I'm launching my application I'm getting the following error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'banane'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.teletubies.bitecouille.BitecouilleApplication.main(BitecouilleApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]

2023-03-24T15:09:06.060+01:00  WARN 4200 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
```

- I created a user "banane" granting all the privileges
- Tried to switch with root user but same issue
- Mysql server instance is running, I can connect, with both users without any issue
- database App exists

This is my application.properties file & pom.xml

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/
spring.datasource.username=banane
sprind.datasource.password=banane
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.teletubies</groupId>
    <artifactId>bitecouille</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bitecouille</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>3.0.0-M4</spring-boot-admin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Issue is in properties file, there is a typo, change below property :-

```
sprind.datasource.password=banane
```

to

```
spring.datasource.password=banane
```

And try running the application